# Mock returns null when mocking using Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I might be missing something obvious here. Using Asp.Net core background service. The simplified setup is as follows:

**SUT**

```
public class OrderService: BaseOrderService 
{
    IConsumer<string, string> _consumer;

    public OrderService(IBuilder consumerBuilder, ILogger logger) : base(logger)
    {
        _consumer = consumerBuilder.Build(() => Provider);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseOrderService: BackgroundService
{
    protected BaseOrderService(ILogger logger){}

    ....
    ....
}
```

**IBuilder**

```
public interface IBuilder
{
    IConsumer<string, string> Build(Func<string> providerFunc);
}
```

**Unit test**

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestDescription()
{
    var mockBuilder = new Mock<IBuilder>();
    var mockConsumer = new Mock<IConsumer<string, string>>();
    mockBuilder.Setup(x => x.Build(It.IsAny<string>)).Returns(mockConsumer.Object);

    var sut = new OrderService(mockBuilder.Object, NullLogger.Instance);
    await sut.StartAsync(default);
    ....
    ....
}
```

**Question**

- Upon running my test, in the OrderService constructor, calling `_consumer = _consumerBuilder.Build(()=> Provider)` returns **null**, although I have provided the mock setup in the test.

What am I missing? Any pointers will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrong argument matcher was used.

The mocked member expected `Func<string>`

```
IConsumer<string, string> Build(Func<string> providerFunc);
```

But your code setup `It.IsAny<string>`

```
mockBuilder
    .Setup(x => x.Build(It.IsAny<string>)) //<-- WRONG
    .Returns(mockConsumer.Object);
```

It should be `It.IsAny<Func<string>>()`

```
 mockBuilder
    .Setup(x => x.Build(It.IsAny<Func<string>>())) //<--
    .Returns(mockConsumer.Object);
```